# count field dynamically under $bucket boundaries in mongo aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am using Mongo aggregate framework, suppose if i am having collection structure like this

```js
[
  {
    _id: 123,
    name: "john",
    age: 30,
    fruit: "apple",
    
  },
  {
    _id: 345,
    name: "moore",
    age: 45,
    fruit: "mango",
    
  },
  {
    _id: 545,
    name: "carl",
    age: 30,
    fruit: "grape",
    
  },
  {
    _id: 96,
    name: "shelby",
    age: 25,
    fruit: "apple",
    
  },
  {
    _id: 86,
    name: "loris",
    age: 48,
    fruit: "mango",
    
  },
  {
    _id: 76,
    name: "carl",
    age: 55,
    fruit: "grape"
  }
]
```

I want to query and create a pipeline such that it return the count of particular fruit which lie under the duration which $bucket boudaries have created: for example result should look like this...

```js
[
  {
    "_id": Specific_Boudary,
    "userCount": Number_Of_Users_Lie,
    "fruitsLie": [
                    {fruit_names_of_user_in_this_boundaries : fruit_counts},
                  ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "userCount": 3,
    "fruitsLie": [
                    {apple: 2},
                    {grape: 1}
                  ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 40,
    "userCount": 2,
    "fruitsLie": [
                    {mango: 2}
                 ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "more than 50",
    "userCount": 1,
    "fruitsLie": [
                    {grape: 1}
                 ]
  }
]
```

so under age 30 we have 3 users, in which 2 eats apple and 1 eats grape so `fruitsLie` field is responsible for this calculation.

how many approaches we can have to achieve the solution for this problem with specific $bucket boudaries and please explain thoroughly each stage, I am new to aggregate and currently learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$bucket": {
      "groupBy": "$age",
      "boundaries": [
        0,
        31,
        41,
        51,
        
      ],
      "default": "More than 50",
      "output": {
        "users": {
          $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$users"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        _id: "$_id",
        fruit: "$users.fruit"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id._id",
      "fruitsLie": {
        "$push": {
          "$concatArrays": [
            [],
            [
              [
                "$$ROOT._id.fruit",
                "$$ROOT.count"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      usersCount: {
        $sum: "$$ROOT.count"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "fruitsLie": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$fruitsLie",
          "as": "item",
          "in": {
            "$arrayToObject": "$$item"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/njPLalmiAMh)

In this query, we do the following:

1. Using $bucket, we group the documents by age into 4 buckets, (0-30), (31-40), (41-50), and (>50). We collect all the users within a bucket into an array.
2. Now, we unwind the users array, using $unwind.
3. Now, using $group, we calculate, the counts for each fruit within each bucket.
4. Again using $group, now we accumulate counts for each bucket, into `fruitsLie` array.
5. Finally, using `$arrayToObject`, we convert elements of `fruitLie` array to a object.